# Swift combine debounce without dropping values

Tags: swift, combine, debouncing

Here is a debounce example:

Data within half a second will be discarded.

```swift
let bounces:[(Int,TimeInterval)] = [
    (0, 0),
    (1, 0.25),  // 0.25s interval since last index
    (2, 1),     // 0.75s interval since last index
    (3, 1.25),  // 0.25s interval since last index
    (4, 1.5),   // 0.25s interval since last index
    (5, 2)      // 0.5s interval since last index
]

let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
cancellable = subject
    .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { index in
        print ("Received index \(index)")
    }

for bounce in bounces {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + bounce.1) {
        subject.send(bounce.0)
    }
}

// Prints:
//  Received index 1
//  Received index 4
//  Received index 5
```

But I want to combine these discarded data, My expected result is:

```
// Prints:
//  Received index [0, 1]
//  Received index [2, 3, 4]
//  Received index [5]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scan` to accumulate the emitted values into an array, the trick is to reset the array once the debounce emits that array:

```swift
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
var reset = false
let cancellable = subject
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .scan([], { reset ? [$1] : $0 + [$1] })
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in reset = false })
    .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in reset = true })
    .sink { indices in
        print ("Received indices \(indices)")
    }
```

There are two pitfalls with this approach, though:

- you need to switch the publisher to the main thread
- the outer variable and `handleEvents` are not too "paradigmic".

Though, you can wrap the not-so-nice logic into it's own publisher, and be a little bit more idiomatic:

```swift
extension Publishers {
    struct DebouncedCollector<Upstream: Publisher, S: Scheduler>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = [Upstream.Output]
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure

        private let upstream: Upstream
        private let dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride
        private let scheduler: S
        private let options: S.SchedulerOptions?

        init(upstream: Upstream, dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, scheduler: S, options: S.SchedulerOptions?) {
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.dueTime = dueTime
            self.scheduler = scheduler
            self.options = options
        }

        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            var reset = false
            upstream
                .receive(on: scheduler)
                .scan([], { reset ? [$1] : $0 + [$1] })
                .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in reset = false })
                .debounce(for: dueTime, scheduler: scheduler, options: options)
                .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in reset = true })
                .receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}

extension Publisher {
    func collectDebounced<S: Scheduler>(for dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, scheduler: S, options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil) -> Publishers.DebouncedCollector<Self, S> {
        .init(upstream: self, dueTime: dueTime, scheduler: scheduler, options: options)
    }
}
```

, and use it like this:

```swift
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let cancellable = subject
    .collectDebounced(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { indices in
        print ("Received indices \(indices)")
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to have new values be available immediately and only to be collected if the subscriber is busy?

Comment: @förschter not sure what you mean by that, publishers usually honor the demand from the subscribers. Anyhow, your sounds like a new kind of publisher, might worth asking a question about it.

Comment: But in this case even the publisher only honors the demand request after 0.5 seconds doesn't it?

Comment: @förschter there's no such thing about honoring demand with a delay, the publisher either honors the demand, or it doesn't. Note that honoring the demand doesn't mean delivery the data right away, it just means that the publisher will not send more items than the subscriber requested.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `debounce` as it is a filtering operation. Instead, use the overload of [`collect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/collect(_:options:)) that takes a `TimeGroupingStrategy` - `collect` *collects* all the elements from upstream into arrays.

```
cancellable = subject
    .collect(.byTime(RunLoop.main, 0.5))
    .sink { group in
        print ("Received group \(group)")
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using it now, but it's a bit inconsistent with what I expected, "collect by time" is more of a "throttle" version.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to accomplish the goal is to write a custom operator for publishers, which will debounce input values and pass them to downstream as an array after the desired delay. I use it in my project and it works perfectly:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

struct CollectDebounce<Upstream: Publisher, S: Scheduler>: Publisher {
  typealias Output = [Upstream.Output]
  typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
  
  let upstream: Upstream
  let dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride
  let scheduler: S
  let options: S.SchedulerOptions?
  
  func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
    let debounceSubscriber = CollectDebounceSubscriber(
      downstream: subscriber,
      dueTime: dueTime,
      scheduler: scheduler,
      options: options
    )
    upstream.subscribe(debounceSubscriber)
  }
}

extension CollectDebounce {
  class CollectDebounceSubscriber<Downstream: Subscriber, S: Scheduler>: Subscriber where Downstream.Input == [Upstream.Output], Downstream.Failure == Failure {
    typealias Input = Upstream.Output
    typealias Failure = Downstream.Failure
    
    private let downstream: Downstream
    private let dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride
    private let scheduler: S
    private let options: S.SchedulerOptions?
    private var lastCancellable: Cancellable?
    private var collectedValues: [Input] = []
    
    init(downstream: Downstream, dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, scheduler: S, options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil) {
      self.downstream = downstream
      self.dueTime = dueTime
      self.scheduler = scheduler
      self.options = options
    }
    
    func receive(subscription: Combine.Subscription) {
      downstream.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
    
    func receive(_ input: Input) -> Subscribers.Demand {
      collectedValues.append(input)
      
      lastCancellable?.cancel()
      lastCancellable = scheduler.schedule(after: scheduler.now.advanced(by: dueTime), interval: .zero, tolerance: .zero) { [weak self] in
        guard let collectedValues = self?.collectedValues else { return }
        _ = self?.downstream.receive(collectedValues)
        self?.collectedValues = []
        self?.lastCancellable?.cancel()
      }
      
      return .none
    }
    
    func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Downstream.Failure>) {
      downstream.receive(completion: completion)
    }
  }
}

extension Publisher {
  func collectDebounce<S: Scheduler>(
    for dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
    scheduler: S,
    options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil
  ) -> CollectDebounce<Self, S> {
    return CollectDebounce(upstream: self, dueTime: dueTime, scheduler: scheduler, options: options)
  }
}
```

And use it as a publisher's operator:

```swift
yourPublisher
  .collectDebounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
  .sink { array in
    // get array of debounced collection
  }
```